# there are problem when i install redux-devtools-extension

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

i cant use composeWithDevTools because he show the error

how can i fix this error :

```
 npm i redux-devtools-extension
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: ecommerce-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: redux@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/redux
npm ERR!   redux@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer redux@"^3.1.0 || ^4.0.0" from redux-devtools-extension@2.13.9
npm ERR! node_modules/redux-devtools-extension
npm ERR!   redux-devtools-extension@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-17T19_37_24_520Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-17T19_37_24_520Z-debug-0.log
PS D:\course\ecommerce-app>
```

my versions:-

"redux-thunk": "^3.1.0",

"redux": "^5.0.1",

"react-scripts": "5.0.1",

"react-redux": "^9.1.0",

"react": "^18.2.0",

Comment: Try deleting your `node_modules` and then repeating the command. Maybe your existing items are interfering with the resolution of the combinations you have selected.

Comment: This package has been deprecated

I think if you use google chrome you can download the redux dev tool extension.

Comment: It says it needs a version of redux older 5

Comment: What is unclear about the peer dependency issue? The version of `redux` you are using is too new for the older deprecated `redux-devtools-extension` package you are trying to install. Either revert the peer dependencies to compatible versions, or use `@redux-devtools/extension` like the `redux-devtools-extension` documentation suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering indicates that there's a version conflict between redux and redux-devtools-extension. You can use @redux-devtools/extension as suggested.

Solution:

In terminal:

```
npm install --save @redux-devtools/extension
```

In code:

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from "@redux-devtools/extension";
```